# Checking an apache -D parameter in php?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am currently using the flag `-D var_name` to start apache on certain machines so that I can use the apache conditional block `<IfDefine !var_name>` to apply certain apache directives.

Is there any way to check these apache parameters in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - to have access to them within there, you'll probably want to set it up to be passed through to an environment variable (which you can then check within PHP):

```
SetEnv var_name ${var_name}
```